# Does a FIR filter $H(z)$ with maximally flat passband group delay response satisfy $|H(e^{i\omega})| \leq 1$?

Tags: finite-impulse-response, lowpass-filter, group-delay

From this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/659456) (*Maximally flat low-pass FIR filters with reduced delay*) and others, I know that it is possible to impose maximally flat passband group delay response constraints. Suppose that I do not care about magnitude response and simply wish to obtain a FIR delay filter. But I do wish to impose maximally flat passband group delay response such that $G(\omega) = D + O(\omega^N)$, where $D$ is desired delay. I know that causal (anti-)symmetric filters of order $2N$ has delay of $N$, but I want to be able to control group delay response and $D \neq N$.

Would such a filter satisfy magnitude response $|H(\omega)| \leq 1$ for all frequencies when $|H(0)|=1$?

Comment: The basic `sinc()` filter has a flat group delay. In fact, all linear phase FIRs have a flat group delay. Must/do they have flat magnitude?

Comment: Why do you need a negative group delay? The filter with impulse response `[0,0,0,0,1]` has a (group) delay $D=4$ and is completely flat. Do you need non-integer delays? Please update the question, and I'll reopen it once we have some clarity.

Comment: I think the question has a trivial answer. All FIR filters have a bounded frequency response, so the constraint $|H(\omega)|\le 1$ can always be satisfied by appropriate scaling. Obviously, scaling doesn't change the group delay.

Comment: @MattL. Edited the question. $|H(0)|=1$.